# very specific substring retrieval and split

Tags: python, logging, substring

i know there are tons of posts about sub-stringing, believe me i have searched through many of them looking for an answer to this.

i have many strings, lines from a log, and i am trying to categorize and parse them.

they look something like this:

> /long/file/name/with.dots.and.extension:Jan 01 12:00:00 TYPE Static
> Message;Dynamic Message

where the filename is the file where the log is located, the date is the date/time that the message was put into the log, and the TYPE is the type of message, and then the message is composed of two parts, a static part and a dynamic part, the static part does not change for the message and the dynamic part can change (obviously) and they are split by a `;` but there can be more `;` in the dynamic part.

i want to be able to extract the Static Message, and the Dynamic Message.

so far i have been using something like this:

```
parts = line.split(";")
static = parts[0]
dynamic = ";".join(parts[1:])
```

not very pretty. and also my static part contains the filename and the date and the type, which i do not want. so then i thought i would do something like this:

```
parts = " ".join(":".join(line.split(":")[1:]).split(" ")[4:]).split(";")
static = parts[0]
dynamic = ";".join(parts[1:])
```

which i have tried, and it works to some extent, except sometimes the filename might have a space, or the TYPE might have a space or something isnt working properly and i sometimes get the TYPE as part of the static message... efficiency is an issue since these are thousands of lines of logs which must be parsed and categorized daily. so i am wondering if there is a better way to do this other than this hack-job??

**edit:** i thought i would provide more examples of lines in the log. to fix what i said earlier, there are a few types of entries.

> /long/file/name/with.dots.and.extension:Jan 01 12:00:00 TYPE Static
> Message;Dynamic Message
>
> /long/file/name/with.dots.and.extension:Jan 01 12:00:00 MODULE.NAME TYPE THREAD.OR.CONNECTION.INFORMATION Static
> Message;Dynamic Message

so as you can see - there are some two types of log entries. those without modules and those with, those with modules can either be connected to connections, and some to threads.
this makes the parsing harder.

Comment: opened a new question for help with a regular expression, as @Martijn Pieters said. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248696/python-regex-conditional-substring-extraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the split to the first ';' only:

```
static, dynamic = line.split(';', 1)
```

Your static part splitting might take a little more doing, but if you know the number of spaces is going to be static in the first part, perhaps the same trick could work there:

```
static = static.split(' ', 4)[-1]
```

If the first part of the line is more complex (spaces in the TYPE part) I fear that removing everything before that is going to be a more difficult affair. Your best bet is to figure out the limited set of values `TYPE` could assume and to use a regular expression with that information to split the static part.

Comment: so your suggestion is to use a regular expression? which means i would be running a regular expression on each line of log. for thousands of logs, each day. wont that be very heavy?

Comment: @InbarRose: Depends entirely on your RE; regular expressions can be *very fast* if coded correctly. A '(this|that|the other)' selection in a regular expression can beat a complicated split, test and join setup anytime.

Comment: Why not static = static.split(' TYPE ', 1)[-1] for the second part?

Comment: @fp: I understood `TYPE` to be dynamic, e.g. it's one of a set of values such as `STORE`, `RETRIEVE`, or something like that.

Comment: @InbarRose: For what it's worth, I maintain a system that parses tens of thousands of lines per day with a regular expression *only*.

Comment: Right. Are TYPE and Static Message known lists? I suppose the messages can have spaces in them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters im writing one right now, to test, but i am having trouble on lookahead/lookbehinds because the `THREAD.OR.CONNECTION.INFORMATION` is only present if there is `MODULE.NAME` it wont parse correctly... my regex so far is something like: `\b(?:.*?):(?:\w{3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?:\s+?)(?:[\S|\.]*?(?:\s*?))?(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE2)|(?:TYPE3))(?:\s+?)(?:\S*?(?:\s+?))?(.+?){1}(?:;(.+?){1})?\b`

Comment: @InbarRose: I smell a separate question coming up.. you can get rid of any of the non-grouping parens around the `TYPEx` values, btw. Also, don't worry about *validating* your log lines, only about *parsing* them. In other words, if there *is* a `THREAD.OR.CONNECTION.INFORMATION` part but there isn't a `MODULE.NAME` part, so what?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, i will probably open this to a separate question now. and then i will link it in the comments. thank you so far, i think regex might be the solution i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
>>> regexp = re.compile("^([\/.\w]*)\:(\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s([A-Z]*)\s([\w\s]*)\;([\w\s]*)$")
>>> regexp.match(line).groups()
('/long/file/name/with.dots.and.extension', 'Jan 01 12:00:00', 'TYPE', 'Static Message', 'Dynamic Message')
```

Comment: thank you, but i have already progressed in a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248696/python-regex-conditional-substring-extraction