# python regex conditional substring extraction

Tags: python, regex, logging, python-2.6

i am opening this question because it seems my original question requires a new direction: [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247651/very-specific-substring-retrieval-and-split/12247791#comment16418144_12247791)

i would like to create a regular expression that can extract STATIC MESSAGE and DYNAMIC MESSAGE from the following types of log-entries:

> /long/file/name/with.dots.and.extension:Jan 01 12:00:00 TYPE Static
>   Message;Dynamic Message
>
> /long/file/name/with.dots.and.extension:Jan 01 12:00:00 MODULE.NAME
>   TYPE THREAD.OR.CONNECTION.INFORMATION Static Message;Dynamic Message

one log entry type has a simple structure:

`file:date TYPE STATIC;DYNAMIC`

the other is not so simple when trying to be parsed with regex:

`file:date MODULE.NAME TYPE CONNECTION.OR.THREAD STATIC;DYNAMIC`

where the `MODULE.NAME` and `CONNECTION.OR.THREAD` are either both present or not present.

my regular expression so far which works on the first type of log entry is:

```
(?:.*?):(?:\w{3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?:\s+?)(?:[\S|\.]*?(?:\s*?))?(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE2)|(?:TYPE3))(?:\s+?)(?:\S+?(?:\s+?))?(.+){1}(?:;(.+)){1}
```

but whenever i get to the second type of entry, i am also getting the CONNECTION.OR.THREAD as part of my first capturing group.

i am hoping for a way to use the lookahead or lookbehind feature so that i can capture `STATIC` and `DYNAMIC` and ignore the `CONNECTION.OR.THREAD` part if there is a `MODULE.NAME` ?

i hope this question is clear, please refer to my original if it seems a bit bleak. thank you.

**EDIT:** for clarification. every line of the log is different then the others, each line starts with a filepath, then a `:` then the date, in the following format: `MMM DD HH:MM:SS` and then it gets tricky, either a `MODULE.NAME` which varies, followed by the `TYPE` which also varies, followed by `CONNECTION.OR.THREAD` which varies, or with just the `TYPE`. after which there is the `STATIC MESSAGE` then a `;` then a `DYNAMIC MESSAGE` both the static and dynamic message vary, the usage of the term `STATIC` is simply because an error can be for instance "unable to connect to server; server1.com" so the static part of the error is "unable to connect to server" and the dynamic part is "server1.com"

Comment: You need to be explicit what parts of your log lines are placeholders for content that varies from one line to the next, and what parts are truly static. For the parts that can vary, stating that there is a limited list of possibilities will also help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have made an edit, hopefuly it clears things up.

Comment: what does "static" mean? Is it a fixed string/a list of fixed strings?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i explained it in my edit: the "static" message is a bit confusing, just pretend it says "part1;part2"

Comment: Right, then *unless there is a more specific pattern to `CONNECTION.OR.THREAD` and `TYPE` than just their presence*, then these lines are almost impossible to parse reliably. There is no way to distinguish these from the static part of the line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes there is. between DATE and TYPE there is either a single space and then the TYPE, or a space followed by a MODULE.NAME followed by a space. then then the TYPE. in the second case, it means that the TYPE is followed by a CONNECTION.OR.THREAD which like the MODULE.NAME has no spaces, simply a connection of letters/digits split with dots. so i need to be able to lookahead/lookbehind or whatever the terminology is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters answered my own question with a solution, you mentioned you are great with regexs please take a look.

Comment: @InbarRose: Being able to use a tool without shooting myself in the foot every time does not equal being great with them...

Comment: Your dummy examples are not helpful. You need to give us some _real_ input (feel free to replace sensitive info with rubbish), the more the better.

Comment: @thg435 you are probably right, but it is unimportant now - i have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment i have made this massive regex:

```
(?:(?:.*?):(?:\w{3}(?: \d{1,2}){2}(?::\d{1,2}){2}))(?:\s+?)(?:(?:(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE3))(?:\s+?)(?:(.+){1};(.+){1}))|(?:\S+(?:\.\S+)+)(?:\s+?)(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE3))(?:\s+?)(?:\S+(?:\.\S+)+)(?:\s+?)(?:(.+){1};(.+){1})))
```

i will split it into parts:

FILE/DATE + SPACE:

```
(?:(?:.*?):(?:\w{3}(?: \d{1,2}){2}(?::\d{1,2}){2}))(?:\s+?)
```

and then EITHER:

SIMPLE: (TYPE STATIC;DYNAMIC)

```
(?:(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE3))(?:\s+?)(?:(.+){1};(.+){1}))
```

OR COMPLEX: (MODULE.NAME TYPE CONNECTION.OR.THREAD STATIC;DYNAMIC)

```
(:?(?:\S+(?:\.\S+)+)(?:\s+?)(?:(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE1)|(?:TYPE3))(?:\s+?)(?:\S+(?:\.\S+)+)(?:\s+?)(?:(.+){1};(.+){1}))
```

it does the trick. but its huge and i think it can be improved. so please if anyone can improve it, please do.

**EDIT:**

there is a problem though. because now there are 4 capturing groups. so i can not know ahead of time if i must look in captured[0:1] or captured[2:3] for my results. anyone have a way to do this that i will not have to check each time if i have something there? or perhaps a way to eliminate empty capturing groups from results, or maybe to only get non-empty results from the list of results? something? my brain is fried.

**EDIT2:**

as @martijn pieters suggested i removed the extraneous grouping this is my current regex:

```
.*?:\w{3}(?: \d{1,2}){2}(?::\d{2}){2}\s+?(?:(?:(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)\s+?(.+){1};(.+){1})|(?:\S+(‌​?:\.\S+)+\s+?(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)\s+?\S+(?:\.\S+)+\s+?(.+){1};(.+){1}))
```

which works fine. i am concerned about `(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)` being miss-interpreted as `TYPE(1|T)YPE(2|T)YPE3` any insight would be appreciated.

also, how best to go about parsing my results - seeing as i will get a list of 4 items with either the first 2 or the second 2 being empty and the other having my static/dynamic results.

**EDIT3:**

okay, i have done a hybrid solution. i have remade my regular expression:

```
.*?:\w{3}(?: \d{1,2}){2}(?::\d{2}){2}\s+?(?:(?:(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3))|(?:\S+(?:\.\S+)+\s+?(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)\s+?\S+(?:\.\S+)+))\s+(.*)
```

i now only have 1 capture group, which is the STATIC;DYNAMIC part. once i get this i do what i was doing before (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247651/very-specific-substring-retrieval-and-split?lq=1))

```
for item in captured:
    parts = item.split(";")
    static = parts[0]
    dynamic = ";".join(parts[1:])
```

that is my solution. thank you @Martijn Pieters especially for your help. i hope this can help someone in the future.

Comment: First; try and reduce the groups a little, you seem to have redundant groups where you don't need them (`(?:.*?)` doesn't need a group for example). Second, use `(?P<groupname>..)` namings so you get a dictionary result, much easier to work with. See http://pastie.org/private/iyfwswt3stmvur25v9vu5w for an example we use to parse log lines from a web server.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if i were to give 2 capture groups the same name, what would happen? for instance, if i give the <static> name to both groups capturing static, knowing they are mutually exclusive since they are on either sides of a `|` what will happen?

Comment: That would fail, you cannot give the same name to two groups.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when things are in groups its easier for me to look at the regex, does it improve the efficiency if there are less groups? even if they are non-capture groups? is there a better way to remove empty results from my captured list other than simply iterating over them and checking their length?

Comment: The example I linked to shows you a different way to improve readability; I find your patterns to be extremely unreadable at the moment. `(?:..)` groups do carry meaning for the regular expression, I don't know if the engine recognizes these groups as otherwise meaningless for the match and leave them out. You should only use them when you do need grouping (such as for specifying repeating compound groups or `|` selection groupings) to be on the safe side.

Comment: Also, you are getting really help-vampirish now; SO is not a forum for extended conversations about regular expression conversations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i reduced the groups, does this look okay? or is there something wrong, i am concerned about the `(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)` because i think it might think i mean `TYPE` and then a `1` or a `T` ...etcetc.. ? you are right i am sorry. i have just been stuck on this for a while and you re-ignited my passion for this problem with your regex idea. `.*?:\w{3}(?: \d{1,2}){2}(?::\d{2}){2}\s+?(?:(?:(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)\s+?(.+){1};(.+){1})|(?:\S+(?:\.\S+)+\s+?(?:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3)\s+?\S+(?:\.\S+)+\s+?(.+){1};(.+){1}))`

Comment: Ugh - at this point - I would be turning to the `pyparsing` module, and using that...

Comment: @JonClements im not familiar, can you post an answer with some examples? or how it can be used here?